# Assembly Reference in Loose XAML

Tags: xaml, assemblies, reference, loose

I have scenario where my loose xaml file can contain the custom control from another assembly. How do i make a reference to that assembly. My Loose XAML and assembly are at the same path.

I know the embedded xaml or xaml with in a project, the reference is added like this:
xmlns:WpfToolKit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"

Now how can i give similar type of reference in the loose xaml file.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
xmlns:Awesome="clr-namespace:MyAwesomeNameSpace"
```

And then use your controls as such:

```
<Awesome:MyAwesomeControl />
```

For nice looking schemas, please read this article on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx

You will need the [XmlnsDefinitionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute.aspx) definition on your class.

Hope this helps!

Comment: you had not gone through my problem. Its about assembly reference in loose xaml.

Comment: could you provide some example code how can use XmlnsDefinitionAttribute. I want to give reference of WPFToolkit.dll